# postman "status": 415, "error": "Unsupported Media Type",

Tags: java, webserver, postman

I was trying to creat a class where I could add a client(cliente) to a class(aula)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/aulas/{numero}/{numerocliente}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> addClienteAula(@PathVariable("numero") int nraula, @PathVariable("numerocliente") int nrclente) {
    try {
        AulaService.addAlunoAula(nraula, nrclente);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErroDTO(e), HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }

}
```

here is my request on postman:
`http://localhost:8080/api/aulas/1/23`

and this is how it turns out:

```json
{
    "timestamp": "2020-04-25T00:12:02.300+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'text/plain' not supported",
    "path": "/api/aulas/1/23"
}
```

Comment: Since you don't actually use the body content of the PUT, why did you require `application/xml` in the first place? Remove the `consumes` attribute. --- Similarly, since you never return a response with a body content, why did you specify that you're returning `application/xml`? Remove the `produces` attribute. --- You can also remove the `method` attribute if you change the annotation to `@PutMapping`, which makes `value =` optional, so you should really just have used `@PutMapping("/aulas/{numero}/{numerocliente}")`

Comment: Q should also have included the other details of the Postman request like headers

Answer (score 0):

Mention your  content type in your postman's request header

```
Content-Type application/xml
```